# refresh oauth token using extjs

Tags: ajax, extjs, oauth

I am using extjs Ext.Ajax.request to call REST APIs from my app. I am using oauth to authenticate the REST APIs. I need to add logic to refresh token if token is expired while calling ext.ajax.request and then if expired, then refresh the token and call the API again using the same mechanism. How can I achieve that without making changes in each of the ext.ajax.request calls?

Answer (score 1):

you could monitor the requestexception event of the Ext.data.connection class. 
Using your success handler you can run the failed request again after the access token is successfully obtained, and e.g. logout if the token can not be refreshed.

```js
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
  requestexception: function(conn, response, options) {
    if (response && (response.status === 401 && response.statusText === "Unauthorized")) {
      MyLoginService.refreshToken(function() {
        //success callback
        conn.request(options);
      }, function() {
        //failure callback
        MyLoginService.logout();
      });
    }
  },
}, this);
```